# Minimisation with combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

> Suppose Dianne has a number of friends. She wants to invite **three**
> to her house for dinner every day of the year. What is the minimum
> number of friends she can have if she does not want to invite the same
> three friends more than once?

I reason that the number of friends can be obtained by $ {n \choose 3} = \frac{n!}{3!(n-3)!} = 365$

but this gives me a third-order polynomial which is unsolvable without a computer. I know guess and check works but I am looking for a "more correct" solution that uses mathematics. I know this si also technically incorrect because you cant "choose" out of numbers other then integers. I know the solution but I'm having trouble framing my answer using combinatorics

I also tried applying pigeonhole principle to this question (initially) but that didn't get me anywhere.

Comment: You are asked to find the *minimum* number of friends. For this you do not need a computer, it suffices to have a crude understanding of the $n^3$ function (I would start checking with 15 or 16).

Comment: The answer is $15$, but I was looking for a way that might not need guessing

Comment: You could apply Newton's method or bisection to your polynomial. That seems to me to overcomplicate things; but perhaps you would consider that to be a "more correct solution that uses mathematics", as it uses techniques from numerical analysis which is quite a respectable branch of math.  Personally I'd use guess-and-adjust and move on. By the way, you already used combinatorics when you set up your polynomial.

Comment: If you don't want to guess recall that there are approximately 52 weeks (+1 day) in a year, so that $364\times 6=12\times13\times 14$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\frac{n!}{(3!)^{365}}=365$, because friends must be different every time, although it seems like an absurd number?

Comment: @Alex One or two friends may repeat, sets of all three shouldn't be the same.

Answer (score 1):

It is interesting to notice that you face the same problem as Newton before Newton method !

Simpliying all numbers, you need to solve for $n$ the cubic equatio
$$n^3-3 n^2+2 n-2190=0$$

First guess : $n^3-2190=0 \implies n=\sqrt[3]{2190}=12.9862$; say $n=13$.

Now, make one single iteration of Newton method to get $n=\frac{6077}{431}=14.0998$. So $n=\lceil 14.0998\rceil=15$.